# Jasper Report Dynamic Parameter for UNION Statement

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, union-all

Basically, using *$P!{param}* is working via *iReport Designer 5.6.0*. 
But then after I use the report in the *Java* application, errors occurs.

Heres how the query goes in the report:

```
SELECT t1.column1, 
t2.column2,
t1.column3
$P!{selectParam}
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.key = t2.key
$P!{leftJoinParam}
WHERE 
...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Where

```
selectParam = " ,t3.column1, t3.column2, t3.column3 " <String>
```

And

```
leftJoinParam = " LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT key, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ..., ..., ..., ... FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    ...
) t3  ON t3.key = t1.key " <String>
```

Value of *leftJoinParam* is passed by the Java app to the report wherein the *SELECT...UNION ALL* statement may vary in count of select depending on the data needed for the report.

It is confusing that the report is working alone in *iReport Designer* given some dummy parameter data with the desired output, but is not working in the *Java* app.

Here is the error in my the java app:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Is there any other way so that I can use the *SELECT...UNION ALL* dynamically?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after t1.column3 in your query?

Comment: There is a comma.. Sorry for that.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. My application parameter names was not equal to my report parameter name.. Its now clear that the whole report SQL query can be dynamically modified using $P!{...}..